# EC2 pub/sub pattern in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

Given the following scenario:

- One EC2 instance containing an app *A*, that acts as publisher.
- N EC2 instances containing an app *B*, that acts as subscriber.

and

- Both apps *A* and *B* cannot be exposed on the Internet (internal).
- Apps *B* can be in multiple regions.

What is the AWS service used for this pub/sub pattern?
I am having issues with the subscription part. I would like to use AWS SNS HTTP/HTTPS subscriptions, but internal addresses are not accepted (only public addresses).

> About the following article:
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-subscribe-private-http-endpoint/
>
> I cannot create one AWS Lambda function per subscriber, and for avoid
> that, I will need to maintain a registry of every subscriber internal
> address in my Lambda function in order to route traffic to every
> subscriber, which in fact is a pub/sub pattern inside my Lambda
> function and I don't think is a good solution.

Comment: Do you really need the _same_ message sent to all instances? What are the instances doing?

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein, many thanks for your comment. Yes, I need the same message sent to all instances, this is a "clean local cache" event. Also pulling is not desirable here. Maybe AWS EventBridge is the best service here? I am not very familiar with it..

Answer (score 3):

You could just write **one AWS Lambda function** that calls `describe_instances()` and filters by the Auto-Scaling Group identifier.

Then, it could loop through the list of instances and send an HTTP request to the IP address of each instance.

This is **simpler than using Amazon SNS** because instances do not need to 'register' to receive a message. The mere fact that they belong to the Auto Scaling Group means they will be sent the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to SNS via VPC endpoint you won't traverse the Internet. SNS is a great solution for your use case.

[image: How to connect SNS]

This diagram shows a VPC that contains an Amazon EC2 instance. The instance connects to Amazon SNS through an interface VPC endpoint. This type of endpoint connects to services that are powered by AWS PrivateLink. With this connection established, you can log in to the Amazon EC2 instance and publish messages to the Amazon SNS topic, even though the network is disconnected from the public internet.

As for the subscription, if you can't use HTTP/S protocol you can utilize a Lambda or an SQS queue as a subscriber to SNS and pull from (in case of SQS) or push to (in case of Lambda) the receiving EC2.

Comment: Hello Pawel, many thanks for your answer!! The thing is that I don't know how many *B* EC2 instances (subscribers) I am going to have, as they will autoscale. Also, for this case it is not possible to create a VPC endpoint for each *B* application.

Comment: By the way, the publishing side is fine, I am having issues with the subscription part.

Comment: Please note that also I am not able to create N AWS lambdas (one for each subscriber) nor N SQS Queues. Creating one SQS Queue is not possible because every subscriber need to process the message, and not only the first one pulling it from the queue.

Comment: An alternative solution would be Kinesis Data Stream. An EC2 instance can write to [KDS stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html) and multiple EC2 instances can consume (push or pull) with [just one Kinesis client library](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/kinesis-client-library-enables-multi-stream-processing/).

Comment: Just for reference, here is the recommendation to use AWS Lambda functions to reach 'private' endpoints: [Subscribe a private endpoint to an Amazon SNS topic](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-subscribe-private-http-endpoint/)

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your comments. I will take a look at the KDS approach. Thank you very much! The thing about AWS Lambda function approach is that I cannot create one per subscriber. Please take a look to the edited question.